# Does working with 2 tomcat?

Tags: tomcat

I have the tomcat up with my web app running, but now I am working a new web app with eclipse and tomcat.

How to work in my new web app keeping my other web app running? 
I mean, I want my we app running while i work in my new app where i can run or stop or restart server.

(something like 2 instances or 2 servers)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tomcat can host multiple web apps on one instance. So you can certainly deploy both web apps to the same instance. I am a little unclear of what you are trying to do. If I read it right you dont want to stop the 1st web app while you develop the second one?

You certainly dont always need to stop and start the server while developing a new app.

However if you really want to you can run two tomcat instances on the same machine using different ports.